# SLF4J+Logback to create a file if doesn't exists/ if deleted

Tags: spring-boot, logback, slf4j

I have been researching for this for a long time and doesn't get a solution at all. My requirement is to create a log file if it is not there at the place.
Below is my **logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<property name="LOG_PATH" value="/home/logs" />

<appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/debug.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %p\t%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}\t%r\t%c\t[--%t--]\t%m%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                    </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<logger name="com.example" level="debug"
    additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</logger>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</root>

</configuration>
```

And I have tried changing the configuration to configuration debug="true", but no luck. 
What is the right way to implement this ?

Please don't write to check on file permissions or ask me to use Log4j, I changed my application to use slf4j instead of log4j. If i delete the file also, it should create

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender` for file appending.

```
<appender name="File-Appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/logfile-${timestamp-by-second}.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've said that you worked with Log4j previously make sure you didn't exclude **"spring-boot-starter-logging"** from your **.pom** in tryings to avoid conflicts between Log4j and slf4j.

I'm using the same settings in **logback.xml** and everything is working fine

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg %n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>TRACE</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="testServiceFileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>logs/test_service_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.mycompany.test" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="testServiceFileAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

in pom:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```